# WordPress ACF Pro User Meta on multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite, user-registration, acfpro

I am using ACF Pro to create extra user meta when user register.

I have tried the ACF for user registration on a single site. It works great. But the same fields group won’t work on multisite.

So I check the codes in includes/forms/form-user.php. It only do_action to ‘register_form’. This action is called in wp-login.php, and it is only used for single site user registration. On multisite, WP uses wp-signup.php for user registration. I believe the action “signup_extra_fields” in wp-signup.php can be used to add extra user meta fields.

How can I tell ACF to render extra user meta for the action “signup_extra_fields”.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of ACF and Multisite is that the ACF plugin has to be activated and the ACF group has to be built in each site of the multi.